# Bootstrap Input Text Resize

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, text, input, resize

I am trying to set up a Responsive Input webpage using Bootstrap and I am having 2 primary difficulties
1. Getting the Label on the same line as the Input box
2. Getting the Input boxes to auto-resize when the screen 'real estate' shrinks

Representative code is

```
<html>
<head>
   <title>Try v1.2 Bootstrap Online</title>
   <link href="/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
   <script src="/scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<form class = "form" role = "form">
   <div class = "row form-group">
      <div class="inline-block col-md-6 " style="float: left;" >
         <label class = "control-label float: left;">First Name</label>
         <input type = "text" class = "form-control" id = "firstname" placeholder = "Enter First Name">
      </div>

      <div class="inline-block col-md-6 " style="float: left;" >
         <label class = "control-label float: left;">Last Name</label>
         <input type = "text" class = "form-control" id = "lastname" placeholder = "Enter Last Name">
      </div>
   </div>

   <div class = "form-group">
      <div class = "col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
         <button type = "submit" class = "btn btn-default">Sign in</button>
      </div>
   </div>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

This gives me a form looking like:
[image]

As you can see, the individual Labels are Above their associated Input boxes and I want them In-line.
And when I resize the browser window, the Input boxes do not change size.

What do I need to change in order to get things working like I need?

I thank you in advance for any advice/suggestions you might have to offer.

EDIT - Well by continuing to search the web I finally found examples which address my issue.  Surprisingly enough there were more than one solution.
Some indicate to use **class="form-horizontal"** Forms and other approaches indicate to use **class="form-inline"** Form.
Both approaches appear to result in workable Responsive Forms like I need.
Regardless I will try to work with a modification of them and see where that takes me.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look [here](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_form_horizontal&stacked=h) for better understanding about horizontal forms.

```
  <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="email">Email:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email">
      </div>
    </div>
```